# Goto specific CollectionView cell in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a collectionview containing cells of thumb photos in alphabetical order of name.

On selecting a thumb I want to go to the full photo, for that thumb on the next view, which is a horizontal paging collection view of full photos for the relevant thumbs in the same order as the thumbs.

The full photo collection view is fired from a segue in the thumb view.

If I pick thumb photo number 3 I want to goto full photo number 3 and not to the default which is the first full photo in the paging collection.

Comment: you used the word _question_, but there is no question here at all...

Comment: so, what is your _question_ then?

Comment: I think the question is "what code do I need to write". The answer to that is to figure out how to do it in Objective-C and then translate that into Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution in the end. In my thumb view segue I put

```
let selectedItems:NSArray = thumbCollection.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
let selectedItem:NSIndexPath = selectedItems[0] as NSIndexPath 
selectedPhotoIndex = selectedItem.row slideVC.selectedPhotoIndex = selectedPhotoIndex
```

and in my slideView I have

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { 
    slideCollection.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(320 * CGFloat(selectedPhotoIndex), 0, 320 , 240), animated: false)
}
```